# intellij ant build message looks totally different from eclipse antbuild message

Tags: eclipse, ant, intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ 12.0 here

when i run ant on my project in eclipse, i get a lovely print out that looks very much like     how it looks when i run it from the command prompt.

When i run it on my project in IntelliJ, it looks like someone doesn't like clarity. I've pressed all of the little buttons that IntelliJ offers but none of them make it look like how it looks in eclipse.

What am i meant to do to get meaningful output from IntelliJ (and follow up, why does IntelliJ seemingly default the ant console to look so terrible?)

I don't have any flags (verbose or otherwise) turned on in either ide.

**UPDATE**

A sample: here is the end of my eclipse build:

```
run-checkstyle:
gen-ivy-dependency-images:
     [echo] Converting dot files to images...
run-clirr:
generate-reports:
     [fmpp] - Executing: index.html
     [fmpp] - Executing: macros.ftl
     [fmpp] - Executing: styles.css
     [fmpp] Summary: 3 exe. + 0 xml. + 0 cop. = 3 succ.; 0 warn.; 0 failed
     [echo] Project Portal Generated for theProject here:     C:\MSDE\user\tools\perforce\user\depot\fast\theProject\trunk\install\common\docs/index.html
```

Here is the (roughly, because it is just gibberish so i'm guessing at what is going on ) same ending for my ant build:

```
gen-ivy-dependency-images
if
echo
msde:dot2png-on-fileset
sequential
for
sequential
current:dot2png
sequential
exec
exec
sequential
current:dot2png
sequential
exec
exec
sequential
current:dot2png
sequential
exec
exec
sequential
current:dot2png
sequential
exec
exec
sequential
current:dot2png
sequential
exec
exec
sequential
current:dot2png
sequential
exec
exec
sequential
current:dot2png
sequential
exec
exec
run-clirr
generate-reports
msde:create-website
sequential
current:overview-extract
property
fmpp
- Executing: index.html
- Executing: macros.ftl
- Executing: styles.css
Summary: 3 exe. + 0 xml. + 0 cop. = 3 succ.; 0 warn.; 0 failed
echo
post-code-analysis
sequential
build-release
Build finished for: fast/theProject/1.0
```

Comment: Ant being just a build / automation tool, does the output really matter? Secondly can you please post a small example showing the differences.

Comment: @vikingsteve output matters because sometimes i'm altering our build process and want to check how it runs.

Comment: Ok, and will you post the example outputs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not any way to get the exact output you are looking for. As much as I love IntelliJ IDEA, in my ten years of use, I have always found its Ant output a bit lacking. (But its awesomeness in all other areas makes up for that.) What you show above for the Eclipse output is basically the same as the ant command line output with its indentation.

With IDEA you have two basic options:

1. Tree
2. Text

The tree mode will mimic Ant's indentation but by using GUI tree nodes. The text mode just prints everything out flat (i.e. non indented). You can toggle the mode via the icon [image: Tree/Text Toggle]

Within both modes, you can turn "Show all messages" on and off via the icon [image: Show All Messages] When on, it adds more verbosity.

Personally, I have found Tree Mode, All messages off, and expand all nodes [image: Expand All] (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num Pad +</kbd>) the closest thing to mimicking Ant's output. Although the added icons are a bit annoying. The hassle is you can't search the tree mode output. You have to toggle to the text mode to do that. So in the end, you have to switch between the various modes.

Two other options for you are

1. Use the Terminal tool window to run the Ant commands via command line
2. Create Ant run definition(s) in *Settings > [IDE Settings] > External Tools* (Click the help button on that dialog for more information). Once defined, you can access via the *Tools* menu. You can also define a keyboard shortcut via *Settings > [IDE Settings] > Keymap*. The one downside is this is defined IDE wide, not just for the project. But by using the groups and keyboard shortcuts, that can be managed.